# Import module from parent or sibling directory in Cloud Functions?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-repository

I have a repository structure hosted in a Google Cloud Repository that looks like this for Google Cloud Functions:

```
.
module.py
/common
     module1.py
     module2.py
/cloudfunction1
     main.py
     requirements.txt
/cloudfunction2
     main.py
     requirements.txt
```

Where each of the cloudfunction directories is deployed as a separate cloud function.

What I'd like to do is import modules from either the common directory, or from the root, however utilising a `sys.path.append('..')` approach doesn't appear to work. I presume this is because the cloud function deployment process only includes the files in the directory in which main.py is located?

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you find yourself needing to modify `sys.path` or otherwise import "beyond the top level package", this is generally a code smell in Python that your project is not correctly structured.

In this example of Cloud Functions, one thing you can do is structure your project like this:

```
.
├── common
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
├── main.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Where `main.py` contains both functions:

```
from common import module1, module2

def cloudfunction1(request):
    ...

def cloudfunction2(request):
    ...
```

And you deploy those functions either directly by name:

```
$ gcloud functions deploy cloudfunction1 --runtime python37 --trigger-http
$ gcloud functions deploy cloudfunction2 --runtime python37 --trigger-http
```

Or by entrypoint:

```
$ gcloud functions deploy foo --runtime python37 --entry-point cloudfunction1 --trigger-http
$ gcloud functions deploy bar --runtime python37 --entry-point cloudfunction2 --trigger-http
```

Note that this has some downsides:

- Your `requirements.txt` file needs to contain all the dependencies for both functions
- If you make changes to the `common` directory, you'll need to redeploy both functions

That said, if your functions are so related that they share common code and often need to be deployed together, a better option might be to make them part of a single App Engine app. (This only applies if they both use HTTP triggers).

Comment: Thanks Dustin, that's useful food for thought, I appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Comment: Does `requirement.txt` having to contain all the dependencies for both functions decrease the performance of any of the cloud function?

Comment: It may make your deployments slightly longer (because it has to install extra dependencies) but it will have no effect on how quickly your function runs.

Comment: Hi @Mike, does this answer your question? It seems to have helped some other folks, are you able to mark this as accepted?